# Trigger update of Bokeh plot upon new data point in stream

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a plot in Bokeh to visualize data from a live data-feed. I'm fairly new to Bokeh at this point. The data stream is a stream of files where the data for the plots first requires to be extracted and then pre-processed before being visualized. This part is currently handled by the python `watchdog` package, where the processing is triggered upon the appearance of a new file in the streams that are monitored.

The output of this is a dictionary holding all the information *for this particular datapoint* needed in the plots handled by the Bokeh app.

My question is, how would I trigger an update of the Bokeh plot when a new datapoint arrives?

I had looked into `add_periodic_callback`, but since I do not know up front when a new datapoint will arrive, nor how much time there will be between them, I risk missing data in the plot. What would be the best way to solve this?

1) Use functionality "x" in Bokeh that I am unaware of, that will trigger an update of the `ColumnDataSource` and the actual plots, exactly when a new datapoint arrives (this would be my preferred solution).

2) Create a form of buffer data source that stores the data for the past NN files and then use `add_periodic_callback` to a function that queries this source to update the `ColumnDataSource`

3) Another solution than the two above, that I don't know of with my limited software development skills.

Comment: Does the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742575/can-i-update-a-bokeh-plot-without-callbacks-from-the-server solve you question?

Comment: Yes, that actually provided the answer I needed, after fiddling a bit with my underlying routines to make them work with asyncio